# How to call state object from different file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, axios, playwright

My setup file runs at first before all tests. After the setup is finished, the system moves on to other tests(using axios in api tests). I m setting **response.token** to **LoginState.authUber(in state.ts)**. But main problem is here into to **axios.ts** file, I add console.log and **LoginState.authUber** returns empty object in axios.ts file.

I tested whether **LoginState.authUber** is written correctly in my **setup.ts** file and confirmed that it is written correctly in the console in the **setup.ts** file. I just can't call it in the **axios.ts** file. I don't understand if I have to wait for something..How can I solve?

this is setup.ts file

```
setup('authenticate as uber user', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto(`${configEnv.baseURL}`)
  await page.locator(LoginRep.emailTextField!).fill(process.env.EMAIL!)
  await page.locator(LoginRep.passwordTextField!).fill(process.env.PASS!)
  await page.locator(LoginPageRep.loginButton!).click()
  page.on('requestfinished', async (request) => {
    if (request.url().match(/authenticate/)) {
      let response = await request.postDataJSON();
      LoginState.authUber = response.token
    }
  })
  await page.waitForSelector("#nav-channels")
  await page.context().storageState({ path: configAuth.AdminAuth });
});
```

This is my state.ts;

```
export const LoginState = {
    authUber:{} as string,
}
```

This is my axios ts file;

```
import axios from "axios";
import { configEnv } from "../config/config"
import { LoginState } from "playwright/tests/login/login.state";

const customAxios = axios.create({
  baseURL: configEnv.apiBaseURL,
});

customAxios.interceptors.request.use(
  async (config) => {
    if (config.headers) {
      console.log('LoginState.authUber', LoginState.authUber)
      config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${LoginState.authUber}`;
      return config;
    }
    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

export default customAxios
```

Comment: `page.on`'s callback is in a different promise chain. Either promisify it or use [`waitForResponse`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-response)

Comment: Could you give me a sample code @ggorlen did not understood properly

Comment: Does `const request = await page.waitForRequest(request => request.url().match(/authenticate/)); LoginState.authUber = request.postDataJSON().token` work for you instead of `page.on`?